# How to append GUID to existing filenames and save to CSV

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, scripting, guid

I currently have a CSV which contains 1 column that lists many file FullNames. (ie. "\\server\sub\folder\file.ext").

I am attempting to import this CSV, move the file to a separate location and append a GUID to the beginning of the filename in the new location (ie GUID_File.ext). I've been able to move the files, generate the GUID_ but haven't been able to store and reuse the existing filename.ext, it just gets cut off and the file ends up just being a GUID_. I just am not sure how to store the existing filename for reuse.

```
$Doc = Import-CSV C:\Temp\scripttest.csv

ForEach ($line in $Doc)
{
 $FileBase = $Line.basename 
 $FileExt = $Line.extension 
Copy-Item -path  $line.File -Destination "\\Server\Folder\$((new-guid).guid.replace('-',''))_$($Filebase)$($FileExt)"
}
```

If possible, I'm going to also need to store and place all the new GUID_File.ext back into a CSV and store any errors to another file.

Comment: What is the header for your CSV file?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with your logic in your script, but I suspect there is a problem with your CSV file or its headers.

If you comment out the `Copy-Item` line and replace it with `$line.File | Out-host` if will show your your error, I suspect the path is `NULL`.

An alternative would be to just do a `$Doc` and see what it pumps out into your console.

Comment: The header of the column is "File" contents of which are the full share path to the files. (ie. \\Server\sub\folder\file.ext). If I was to guess what the issue is, it would be that the Path and File are contained in the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your question carefully, you want to:

- copy the files listed in the CSV file in the 'File' column.
- the new files should have a GUID prepended to the filename
- you need a new CSV file where the new filenames are stored for later reference
- you want to track any errors and write those to a (log) file

Assuming you have an input CSV file looking something like this:

```
File,Author,MoreStuff
\\server\sub\folder\file.ext,Someone,Blah
\\server\sub\folder\file2.ext,Someone Else,Blah2
\\server\sub\folder\file3.ext,Same Someone,Blah3
```

Then below script does hopefully what you want.
It creates new filenames by prepending them with a GUID and copies the files in the CSV listed in column `File` to some destination path.
It outputs a new CSV file in the destination folder like this:

```
OriginalFile,NewFile
\\server\sub\folder\file.ext,\\anotherserver\sub\folder\38f7bec9e4c0443081b385277a9d253d_file.ext
\\server\sub\folder\file2.ext,\\anotherserver\sub\folder\d19546f7a3284ccb995e5ea27db2c034_file2.ext
\\server\sub\folder\file3.ext,\\anotherserver\sub\folder\edd6d35006ac46e294aaa25526ec5033_file3.ext
```

Any errors are listed in a log file (also in the destination folder).

```
$Destination = '\\Server\Folder'
$ResultsFile = Join-Path $Destination 'Copy_Results.csv'
$Logfile     = Join-Path $Destination 'Copy_Errors.log'
$Doc         = Import-CSV C:\Temp\scripttest.csv

# create an array to store the copy results in
$result = @()
# loop through the csv data using only the column called 'File'
ForEach ($fileName in $Doc.File) {
    # check if the given file exists; if not then write to the errors log file
    if (Test-Path -Path $fileName -PathType Leaf) {
        $oldBaseName = Split-Path -Path $fileName.Path -Leaf
        # or do $oldBaseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($fileName)
        $newBaseName = "{0}_{1}" -f $((New-Guid).toString("N")), $oldBaseName
        # (New-Guid).toString("N") returns the Guid without hyphens, same as (New-Guid).Guid.Replace('-','')

        $destinationFile = Join-Path $Destination $newBaseName
        try {
            Copy-Item -Path $fileName -Destination $destinationFile -Force -ErrorAction Stop
            # add an object to the results array to store the original filename and the full filename of the copy
            $result += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                'OriginalFile' = $fileName
                'NewFile'      = $destinationFile
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error "Could not copy file to '$destinationFile'"
            # write the error to the log file
            Add-content $Logfile -Value "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) - ERROR: Could not copy file to '$destinationFile'"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "File '$fileName' does not exist"
        # write the error to the log file
        Add-content $Logfile -Value "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) - WARNING: File '$fileName' does not exist"
    }
}
# finally create a CSV with the results of this copy.
# the CSV will have two headers 'OriginalFile' and 'NewFile'
$result | Export-Csv -Path $ResultsFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: This does everything I need it to do. Thank you Theo.

Comment: @AJD25 oops, just a minor mistake: Where it says `$((Get-Date).ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))` it SHOULD have been `$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))`. (four `y`s instead of three)

Answer (score 1):

> I currently have a CSV which contains 1 column that lists many file FullNames. (ie. "\server\sub\folder\file.ext").

This isn't a CSV.  It's just a plaintext file with a list.

Here's how you can accomplish your goal, however:

```
foreach ($path in (Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\scripttest.csv))
{
    $file = [System.IO.FileInfo]$path
    $prefix = (New-Guid).Guid -replace '-'
    Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "\\Server\Folder\${prefix}_$file"
}
```

This will take your list, convert the item into a `FileInfo` type it can work with, and do the rest of your logic.

Comment: There are a lot of other columns in the CSV, but for use in this part of the script I am only using this Column. I'll give this a try in the morning once I can access the separate VMs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on:

> `$FileBase = $line.basename`
>   `$FileExt = $line.extension`

it sounds like you mistakenly think that the `$line` instances representing the objects returned from `Import-Csv C:\Temp\scripttest.csv` are [`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) instances, but they're not:

**What [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) outputs are `[pscustomobject]` instances whose *properties* reflect the column values of the input CSV, and the values of these properties are invariably *strings*.**

You must therefore use `$line.<column1Name>` to refer to the column containing the full filenames, where `<column1Name>` is the name defined for the column of interest in the header line (the 1st line) of the input CSV file.

If the CSV file has no header line, you can specify the column names by passing an array of column names to `Import-Csv`'s `-Header` parameter, e.g.,
`Import-Csv -Header Path, OtherCol1, OtherCol2, ... C:\Temp\scripttest.csv`

I'll assume that the column of interest is named `Path` in the following solution:

```
$Doc = Import-Csv C:\Temp\scripttest.csv

ForEach ($rowObject in $Doc)
{
  $fileName = Split-Path -Leaf $rowObject.Path
  Copy-Item -Path $rowObject.Path `
            -Destination "\\Server\Folder\$((new-guid).guid.replace('-',''))_$fileName"
}
```

Note how `Split-Path -Leaf` is used to extract the filename, including extension, from the full input path.

Comment: There is a lot more data in the CSV which is going to be used during another process but for this Move/Copy-Item piece is only using the "Path" column as you have called it. I like how you have used the Split-Path to separate the file path from the actual file.ext. I thought this was the issue but the solution just wasn't coming to me. Thank you. I will test and respond once I have access to the VMs in the morning. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone for the solutions. All of them worked and worked well. I chose Theo as the answer for the fact that his solution solved the error logging and stored all the new renamed  files with GUID_File.ext new to the existing CSV info.

Thank you all.